# Assigning between types with the same keys - "Type '...' is not assignable to type 'never'."

Tags: typescript

In my application I'm using values that can be either static values or functions returning those values.

For the typescript, I defined the static values with their types like this

```js
type Static = {
  key1: number;
  key2: string;
};
```

and then derived a type for the dynamic values using `keyof Static`:

```js
type DynamicValue<T> = () => T;
type Dynamic = {[key in keyof Static]: DynamicValue<Static[key]>};
```

which - in my understanding - should be exactly the same as writing this:

```js
type DynamicValue<T> = () => T;
type Dynamic = {
  key1: DynamicValue<number>;
  key2: DynamicValue<string>;
};
```

(and in fact, both produce the same error in the code below)

Now I have a function that takes dynamic values and creates static values from them, and that is where the problem shows:

```js
function dynamicToStatic(d: Dynamic): Static {
  const o: Static = {key1: 0, key2: ''};
  
  for (const [key, callback] of Object.entries(d))
    // the left-hand side of this assignment is marked with error:
    //   "Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'."
    o[key as keyof Static] = callback();

  return o;
}
```

(there's also a variant of the function that is supposed to take a `Partial<Dynamic>` as argument and return a `Partial<Static>`, and that shows a similar error: "Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.")

It seems to be unrelated to `Object.keys`, since this version has the same error:

```js
function dynamicToStatic(d: Dynamic): Static {
  const o: Static = {key1: 1, key2: ''};
  
  const keys = ['key1', 'key2'] as Array<keyof Static>;
  for (const key of keys)
    o[key] = d[key]();

  return o;
}
```

I know that I can silence that error by replacing the problematic line with

```js
(o as any)[key as keyof Static] = callback();
```

but clearly typescript thinks that I've been doing something problematic, but I just can't figure out what it is that might be a problem here.

So, why am I seeing this error with  the code above? What exactly has the type 'undefined' / 'never' from the error-message and why?

([full code in the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAIiB2BDAtgSwMYDVEBsCuEAPACoB8UAvFABQCUl5xA3AFCiRTb5FmVTFQAPrAQoMXAiVKs24aAGVgiYBj4BvFlCgBrCCACMALijw8yAEYQATqy26QAJmMBnYFdTwA5qwC%20M9tBwSGjo6gDa9lAeOnoA9gBmUIrKGAC6xkFiWLiSySroEXqppH4sAPRlUM4AFrF4OAAmUJZQEACOeKgAbrgQ8MBQwLGG5ZUBIsGqVBoVWjEGGaIhEkSmFtbSo3P2ThNZK4Su7l6bs6UsLPF48OgqsfBQDUsYxLF5GNQNi5PotMbvoQ0WnQ91cUGGSSU%20XU9iMUH0ABp5rsAOQo0paTRQeKxKw0EHwMGFEBI9C4HDmRDobSpcGJADy5gAVhBbgA6PpuVAQZyfWi0LFaWLEqCIZzzBKQlLoWlUMk4ClU7R0GRaKwQYB4KwPWK%20C5XG53B5gRBWFS4TIhV4Az7GAAKpvNOEIlow5GmPj%20UAdZtQuEIAPIQKgBLBEJ9ToDULd6nOWhxeOooYGxNJ5Mp1NpksZLPZnPcPL5Arm4JFYoliQBspD6aVKouao1Wp1viAA))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `o` can contain values of `string` or `number`, in this assignment here

```
o[key as keyof Static] = callback();
```

`callback` must return `string & number` to be sound (since to be safe, you have to somehow satisfy both `string` and `number`). Otherwise, the you might be assigning a string to a number and vice versa! However, `string & number` is **impossible**, which is why it gets reduced to `never` (that's where `never` is coming from). Since you can't assign `string | number` to `never`, you get an error.

This error is *correct* and does hint at this potentially unsafe assignment, but we know that it isn't since the key and callback should have matching types. There are multiple ways to get around this.

One would be to cast to `never`. It looks odd and might need someone else a little time to digest, but it does work since `never` is assignable to `never`:

```
o[key as keyof Static] = callback() as never;
```

I like this one since it's the simplest... but you could also use `Object.defineProperty` (or even `Reflect.defineProperty`):

```
Object.defineProperty(o, key, { value: callback() });
```

Lastly, another way would be a helper function for assignments:

```
function assign<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, key: K, value: T[K]) {
  o[key] = value;
}
```

and then you can just cast the key to `keyof Static`:

```
assign(o, key as keyof Static, callback());
```